# Ansible role depend on other roles

Tags: ansible

I have a role, `foo` that installs a file `{{ foo_path }}` that's defined in `roles/defaults/main.yml`.

I have a second role, `bar` that depends on that file being there.   I could put `foo` in the `roles/meta/main.yml` `dependencies` but then it will run the entire role which is not ideal. I could potentially tag the task in the role that creates the file, but that's not really scalable, and introduces problems when I'm not the owner of that role's code.

I could just `assert` that the file is there, but the problem is that I don't know where "there" is.

How can I load the `foo_path` var from a different role without the overhead of running the play?

Answer (score 2):

Given the *foo* defaults

```yaml
shell> cat roles/foo/defaults/main.yml 
foo_path: /tmp/test.txt
```

There are more options:

1. Include the *foo* defaults into a dictionary and get the variable *foo_path*

```yaml
shell> cat pb_bar.yml
- hosts: localhost
  pre_tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: roles/foo/defaults/main.yml
        name: foo_defaults
    - debug:
        var: foo_defaults.foo_path
      when: debug|d(false)|bool
    - set_fact:
        foo_path: "{{ foo_defaults.foo_path }}"
  roles:
    - bar
```

Use the variable in the role *bar*

```yaml
shell> cat roles/bar/tasks/main.yml
- stat:
    path: "{{ foo_path }}"
  register: foo_path_st
- debug:
    var: foo_path_st
  when: debug|d(false)|bool
- assert:
    that: foo_path_st.stat.exists
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb_bar.yml -e debug=true

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [include_vars] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  foo_defaults.foo_path: /tmp/test.txt

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Assert foo_path] ***********************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [bar : stat] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [bar : debug] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  foo_path_st:
    ansible_facts:
      discovered_interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python3
    changed: false
    failed: false
    stat:
      ...
      exists: true
      ...
      path: /tmp/test.txt

TASK [bar : assert] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

2. Structure the roles' tasks

```yaml
shell> tree roles
roles
├── bar
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
└── foo
    ├── defaults
    │   └── main.yml
    └── tasks
        ├── assert_foo_path.yml
        ├── install_foo_path.yml
        └── main.yml

5 directories, 5 files
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/foo/tasks/assert_foo_path.yml 
- stat:
    path: "{{ foo_path }}"
  register: foo_path_st
- debug:
    var: foo_path_st
  when: debug|d(false)|bool
- assert:
    that: foo_path_st.stat.exists

shell> cat roles/foo/tasks/install_foo_path.yml 
- file:
    path: "{{ foo_path }}"
    state: touch

shell> cat roles/foo/tasks/main.yml 
- name: Install foo_path
  include_tasks: install_foo_path.yml
- name: Assert foo_path
  include_tasks: assert_foo_path.yml
```

and use the module [*include_role*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#ansible-builtin-include-role-module-load-and-execute-a-role)

```yaml
shell> cat roles/bar/tasks/main.yml 
- name: Assert foo_path
  include_role:
    name: foo
    tasks_from: assert_foo_path.yml
```

Create playbooks for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb_foo.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - foo

shell> cat pb_bar.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - bar
```

The play will fail if the file is missing

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb_bar.yml -e debug=false

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Assert foo_path] ***********************************************************************

TASK [foo : stat] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [foo : debug] ***************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [foo : assert] **************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: foo_path_st.stat.exists
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Assertion failed

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Create the file

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb_foo.yml -e debug=false

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [foo : Install foo_path] ****************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-321/roles/foo/tasks/install_foo_path.yml for localhost

TASK [foo : file] ****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [foo : Assert foo_path] *****************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-321/roles/foo/tasks/assert_foo_path.yml for localhost

TASK [foo : stat] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [foo : debug] ***************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [foo : assert] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The assert task will succeed now

```yaml
TASK [foo : assert] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed
```

Comment: The splitting of the tasks is interesting, I hadn't thought of that.  I don't necessarily like #1 because the `foo` role will always need that variable to be defined and that is not apparent when creating the play.  It'd also be cumbersome and redundant to have to do that for every playbook that decides to include that role.